# Proving a lemma for a dichotomy

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, rolles-theorem

I am currently trying to prove the Rolle theorem by dichotomy. I think it is possible and I found the following property, that might be useful :

> let $f : [a,b]\to \mathbf{R} $ be a continuous function with $f(a)-f(b)=0$, then there exist $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $a<\alpha<\beta<b$, with $\beta-\alpha\leq\frac{b-a}{2}$ and $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$

To prove this lemma, I thought I'd use the IVT on the following function : 
$$\forall x \in I=\left[a,\frac{a+b}{2}\right], g(x)=f\left(x-\frac{b-a}{2}\right)-f(x)$$

to prove that there exist $\alpha \in I$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$, and then maybe proving that there exist a $\beta$ in $\left[\frac{a+b}{2},b\right]$ such that $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$

From there, the lemma would (?) follow,

Any Help is appreciated, 
T.D

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your lemma. First, I guess $f$ is defined over $[a,b]$ and takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. Second, as it is written, the lemma is false. Are you sure that $f(a)f(b)=0$ is the correct hypothesis?

Comment: Ofc I did a mistake the real hypothesis is f(a)-f(b)=0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x) \ge 0, f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) > 0 \\ \Huge\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{\overline{\phantom{ABC}}\,} \\ x = a \qquad \qquad x = b$$

Without loss of generality, assume that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.  I'll first prove the lemma for the simple case $f \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$ with $f\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right) > 0$.

The auxiliary function $$g(x)=f\left(x-\frac{b-a}{2}\right)-f(x)$$ should be defined on the right-half of the interval $$I=\left[\frac{a+b}{2},b\right].$$

This enables us to see that
\begin{align}
g\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) &= f(a) - f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = 0 - f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) < 0\text{, and} \\
g(b) &= f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) - f(b) = f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) - 0 > 0.
\end{align}

Therefore, there exists $\beta \in I$ such that $g(\beta) = 0$.

$$\text{i.e.} f(\alpha) - f(\beta) = 0 \text{, where } \alpha := \beta - \frac{a+b}{2}.$$

$$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = 0 \\ \huge \overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{\overline{\phantom{AB}}\,} \overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{\overline{\phantom{AB}}\,} \\ x = a \qquad \qquad x = b$$

Then, prove the lemma for another special case $f\ge 0$ on $I$ with $f\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right) = 0$ and that $f$ is *finitely* many roots on $I$.  Since the number of roots of $f$ on $I$ is finite, we can easily reduce this into the simply case: just like a subinterval $[c,d] \subseteq I$ so that $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in (c,d)$.  This reduces to the first case.

[image: continuous function with infinitely many crossings]
Graph of $f(x) = \begin{cases}x \sin(1/x) & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$ ([source of picture](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/238822/290189))

The remaining case is even simpler: $f$ has *infinitely* many crossings with the $x$-axis on interval $I$.  An argument by length should enable you to find the desired subinterval $[\alpha,\beta]$.

---

Edit: this answer addresses the original version of the question.

Your lemma is *false*.  Take $f(x) = 689x$ defined on $[0,8964]$ as a counterexample.  $f(0)f(8964) = 0 \times 8964 = 0$, but since $f$ is *strictly increasing*, $f$ is injective, so *no* distinct interior points $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the domain can satisfy $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$.

Comment: mb, Error corrected.

Comment: Oh, well, thanks, what do you mean by an "argument by length" ?

Comment: @T.D. It's just a name that I created to summarize the details.  Halmos recommends this practice since this facilitates discussion, especially when there's no blackboard/paper.  For the 3rd case, take a sequence (or just three) of roots of $f$ in the interior of $I$.  What can the maximal length of the smallest subinterval formed by these choosen roots be?

Comment: @T.D. Let me use an analogy: the poorest person in a country has wealth $\epsilon$.  What can the minimum wealth of the country be?

Comment: Well first thank you for your time ! Err I'd intuitively say that if the total length of I is L, the max length shall be L/3 ? Tell me if I'm wrong. The minimum wealth can be 0 (please dont use \epsilon,, rather use \varepsilon : $\varepsilon$)

Comment: @T.D. Sorry for late reply.  Thanks for the tips.  In fact, there's a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98013/126386) on [tex.se].  If you divide $I$ into three subintervals, the *maximum* length of the smallest subinterval is $\ell(I)/3$. If the poorest person has wealth $\varepsilon$, other person should have wealth $\ge\varepsilon$, so that country should have wealth $\ge N \varepsilon$. Now, if we impose an upper bound on the country's total wealth $N \varepsilon \le M$, we then get an upper bound on $\epsilon \le M / N$. The idea goes the *same* for the existence of [α,β]

Comment: Okay I just though about the wealth as a real One but my bad here, thks a Lot

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you may ["accept" the answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/290189) by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh, I forgot  to do it